# What git branch model can be used for two productions environment

Tags: git, github

Most git branch models are based on the develop/release/master/hotfix model from nvie: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model

This model assumes you have only one production release, and there's no need to hotfix a previous production version. However, what if you have two productions, one as live, another as demo or backup live, and you want to release to the two environments in two stages with a relatively long gap?

Assuming v1.1 is released to production1, but production2 is still running v1.0, then you found a bug in v1.0 and can not wait for v1.1 to be release. In this case you need hotfix v1.0, but you can't just merge that hotfix to master, because that will commit the hotfix to after tag v1.1, which can't be released until a later time.

In this case, will rebase be my friend? How can I insert the hotfix into master without moving any tags created after the hotfix branch off point?

For example:

# assuming hotfix is branched off tag v1.0

```
git checkout master
git rebase hotfix 
# hotfix is in right place on master, but how can I tag v1.0.1 from there?
# and will tag v1.1 be affected by this rebase?
```

EDIT:
**thinking about it, rebase is a very bad idea, because I would have already pushed to master, rebase a pushed change can't be good.**

Comment: Your hunch is correct. You don't rebase hotfixes - you merge them. Preferably with `--no-ff`. Rebase local repo with public repo to minimize merge conflicts, merge public repo with local repo to push local changes to the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case you need `hotfix v1.0`, but you can't just merge that hotfix to master, because that will commit the hotfix to after tag `v1.1`.

Correct: production2, from now on, must run the `hotfix1.0` branch, and you can tag `v1.0.1` there (in the `hotfix1.0` branch).
`master` only reference major releases, it can't reference all intermediate releases since they could be in a mixed order.

You can also merge/cherry-pick that fix to the `release1.1` branch, which isn't merged back to `master` yet, and which prepares the 1.1 release.

Comment: **master only reference major releases, it can't reference all intermediate releases since they could be in a mixed order.** -- this will work, but then master branch doesn't reflect what has been released to production (the 1.0 hotfix will be merged to release1.1 branch, but on master it looks like that has been fixed for 1.1 rather than 1.0), in this case I wonder why do we need master branch. Isn't it easier to just tag and release from releasing branch?

Comment: @swang Actually, `master` *should* reflect what is in production, as long as you consider there is only *one* production. In this case, you still can merge the release branch back to `master` and tag `master`. But in your case, you have *two* productions, which means `master` can only reflect one of them. I would advise the most recent one in term of version number (the `1.1.x` when delivered). In that instance, the `1.0.x` will have to live in the `hotfix1.0` branch.

Comment: you are right, but what about releasing from the tip of release branch and get rid of master? That seems more straightforward to me, the only compromise is I don't have a branch to see the full history of production ready code.

Comment: @swang in your case (2 prod), you can release from wherever you want. master is more a convention, for contributors to get the most recent production-ready image (since it is the branch checked out by default when cloning).